# Gerrit query option to print just the first line

Tags: python, shell, gerrit

This script works:

```
!#/bin/bash
gerrit_query_output=$(ssh -p 29418 my_review-server.com gerrit query --format=JSON --commit-message change:66664 | head -n 1)
commit_message=$(echo $gerrit_query_output | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['commitMessage']" | grep -v ^Change-Id:)

echo "commit msg= $commit_message"
```

1. Is there an option in gerrit query command to print only first line so I can avoid `| head -n 1` in line 2? json parsing in python fails if gerrit_query_output gets `{"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":9,"moreChanges":false}` as second line.
2. Is there a better way to get commitMessage without `Change-Id:` line, so I can avoid `| grep -v ^Change-Id:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use "[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)" instead of phthon to get the commit message:

```
ssh -p 29418 GERRIT-SERVER gerrit query --format=JSON --commit-message change:CHANGE-NUMBER | jq -r --raw-output '.commitMessage // empty'
```

2) There's no way to do that.